# linux bash regex finds only first occurrence

Tags: regex, linux, match

I need get all match groups from string.
The code bellow shows only 3 groups (first occurrence)

```
#!/bin/bash

str="dn: CN=username1,OU=group1,OU=Users,OU=DOMAIN,OU=All,DC=domain,DC=local cn: username1 dn: CN=username2,OU=group2,OU=Users,OU=DOMAIN,OU=All,DC=domain,DC=local cn: username2 "

rx="dn: CN=([a-zA-Z0-9]+),OU=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"

[[ "$str" =~ $rx ]]
echo "${#BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[5]}"
```

Result is

```
3
dn: CN=username1,OU=group1
username1
group1
```

I am try to use

```
rx="^(dn: CN=([a-zA-Z0-9]+),OU=([a-zA-Z0-9]+))$"
```

but it not working too

Comment: Could you please post sample expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: What about `echo "$str"  | sed 's/dn: /\n/g' | tail -n+2`?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I need to be:
 `6
 dn: CN=username1,OU=group1
 username1
 group1
 dn: CN=username2,OU=group2
 username2
 group2`

Answer (score 0):

Bash is the wrong tool for this.  Try a more capable tool like Perl.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

while (<DATA>)
{
  if (s/^dn: CN=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*)$/$2/)
  {
    print $1, "\n";
    while (s/^,OU=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(.*)$/$2/)
    {
      print $1, "\n";
    }
  }
}

__DATA__
dn: CN=username1,OU=group1,OU=Users,OU=DOMAIN,OU=All,DC=domain,DC=local cn: username1
dn: CN=username2,OU=group2,OU=Users,OU=DOMAIN,OU=All,DC=domain,DC=local cn: username2
```